# Is there a way i can disable the information bar for ActiveX controls using JavaScript or XHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I save this file as test.html and when I opened this file in IE, I am getting Information Bar for ActiveX Controls, Is there any way we can disable this thing using javascript code or jQuery code?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
}
else
        {
window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com/"
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I just wanted to make sure, as I am running locally on my box so that is the reason it is showing ActiveX control Information bar? And Once I upload this file to a remote server and access it from there then this active x bar will not appear??
But is there any way programmatically to disable this information bar? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Mark of the Web (MOTW). We can disable the ActiveX controls warning by putting following code before the opening html tag:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet --> 
<html>
<body>
......
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is call “Mark of the Web (MOTW)”, this is a feature of Windows Internet Explorer that enhances security by enabling Internet Explorer to force Web pages to run in the security zone of the location the page was saved from

Answer (score 0):

The Information Bar you're seeing is unrelated to ActiveX (even though it might say "ActiveX").  It's simply telling you that a IE isn't running scripts on a local file, a security precaution.

- Yes, when accessed via HTTP, the warning won't appear.
- <s>There's no way to programmatic disable it because (1) your code isn't running in the first place; and (2) doing so would circumvent the security restriction that this is meant to be.</s> Use the [MOTW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10326603/201952).

If you just want pages to work on your machine, go to Tools, Internet Options, Advanced, and check Allow active content to run in files on My Computer.  I'd only enable this option while developing, however.